# pipenv install packages for python is not working

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

I am new to Python and therefore I am struggling to resolve the following problem. I installed *pip* and I made a user installation of *pipenv* and then on my project folder I run the command:

```
pipenv install requests
```

which gives me an error saying that the *pipenv command either wrong or cannot be found*.

I added following path on my system environment variables the :

```
C:\Users\andri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts
```

but still it does not work. Does anyone have an idea as to what I should do next in order to fix this? Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

My operating system is Windows.

Here is how I installed pip through cmd

```
C:\Users\andri>python -m pip install -U pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/f3/413bab4ff08e1fc4828dfc59996d721917df8e8583ea85385d51125dceff/pip-19.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 1.5MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 18.1
    Uninstalling pip-18.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-18.1
Successfully installed pip-19.0.3

C:\Users\andri>pipenv install requests
Der Befehl "pipenv" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.

C:\Users\andri>pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from c:\users\andri\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

C:\Users\andri>pip install --user pipenv
Collecting pipenv
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/13/b4/3ffa55f77161cff9a5220f162670f7c5eb00df52e00939e203f601b0f579/pipenv-2018.11.26-py3-none-any.whl (5.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 5.2MB 2.2MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in c:\users\andri\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (40.6.2)
Collecting virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 (from pipenv)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e3/d9/d9c56deb483c4d3289a00b12046e41428be64e8236fa210111a1f57cc42d/virtualenv_clone-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting virtualenv (from pipenv)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/5d/314c760d4204f64e4a968275182b7751bd5c3249094757b39ba987dcfb5a/virtualenv-16.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.0MB 4.7MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0.1 in c:\users\andri\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (19.0.3)
Collecting certifi (from pipenv)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/75/f692a584e85b7eaba0e03827b3d51f45f571c2e793dd731e598828d380aa/certifi-2019.3.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (158kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 837kB/s
Installing collected packages: virtualenv-clone, virtualenv, certifi, pipenv
  The script virtualenv-clone.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\andri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script virtualenv.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\andri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The scripts pipenv-resolver.exe and pipenv.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\andri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed certifi-2019.3.9 pipenv-2018.11.26 virtualenv-16.4.3 virtualenv-clone-0.5.1
```

Comment: Did you install it through? Sudo ? It happens sometimes because it needs to be installed that way so it would be sudo pip install pipenv or if that doesn't work try this one sudo -H pip install -U pipenv . Also do you have virtualenv or another virtual environment the two could be conflicting.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer! I am using windows, is the sudo command still gonna work here? I get an error

Comment: Please include [the exact command(s) you are running, and the exact output, from a "clean state",  and environment details where applicable](/help/mcve). E.g. any virtualenvs involved? What OS? How did you install `pip` and `pipenv`?

Comment: One more: where is your Python installation and is it on `PATH`?

Comment: So after you installed pipenv you tried pipenv install requests.... What is the output of the following: pipenv --python 3.7 . Also have you checked the GitHub for pipenv it is linked https://github.com/pypa/pipenv

Comment: did u manage to resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pip` is actually helpfully warning you about this situation right there...

> The script virtualenv-clone.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\andri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
>     Consider adding this directory to PATH...
>    The script virtualenv.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\andri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
>     Consider adding this directory to PATH...
>    The scripts pipenv-resolver.exe and pipenv.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\andri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
>     Consider adding this directory to PATH...

You will need to add that directory

> C:\Users\andri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts

to your PATH environment variable; there are many ways to do it, see e.g. [Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows/9546345)

Another option is to just always use

```
C:\...> C:\Users\andri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\pipenv install
```

but I think that might get a little stale quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I have written on my question, I have already done this step. Hence, the path is already added on the variables

Comment: Try opening a new Command Prompt then. Sometimes path changes don't get directly applied.

Answer (score 0):

```
  The script virtualenv.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\andri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH
```

There is your answer. The `Scripts` directory with utility scripts for packages installed per-user is not on `PATH`, so your command shell won't find them unless you add it.

If you have *just* added it to `PATH` via the Control Panel, see [windows - Why are changes to my PATH not being recognised? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/107521/why-are-changes-to-my-path-not-being-recognised)

Comment: But I added this on the path as mentioned in my question

Comment: @ffblord https://superuser.com/questions/107521/why-are-changes-to-my-path-not-being-recognised

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this same problem, But I quietly not figured out the solution yet. But I realize that It is the problem of the latest version of python. (Python 3.10.5 in my case). Therefore, I downloaded the lower version of python (Python 3.9.9) and it solves the issue.

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with the version of Python. If that fixed it for you, it's probably because your 3.10.5 was not installed quite correctly, while your fresh 3.9.9 installation was correct.

Comment: Downgrading Python is often the solution when you're trying to install a package that doesn't support the latest version of Python yet. But the PATH issue OP asks about could apply to any and all versions.